# How to find constant term of binomial

Tags: algebra

There is supposed to be a command or set of commands to find the constant term of a binomial expression like

$$
\left(-2x^4 + \dfrac{-5}{x}\right)^{25}
$$

```
(-2*x^4 - 5/x)^25
```

but I can manage to find it.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cases[(\[Minus]2 x^4 \[Minus] 5/x)^25 // Expand,  x_ /; NumericQ[Simplify[x]]]

Comment: Also: `In[127]:= Residue[1/x*(-2*x^4 - 5/x)^25, {x, 0}]

Out[127]= -162139892578125000000`

Comment: Moreover (and I make this as a general remark), when you want to find such a term it often pays to look where you last remember having seen it, and retrace your steps from there.

Answer (score 17):

```
Coefficient[(-2*x^4 - 5/x)^25, x, 0]
(*    -162139892578125000000    *)
```

Comment: Superb, thank you!!

Comment: Note: `SeriesCoefficient` is a much safer option (e.g., `Coefficient[Exp[x],x,0]` returns `Exp[x]` while `SeriesCoefficient` returns the expected answer).

Answer (score 6):

The following, also, works:

```
(-2*x^4 - 5/x)^25 // SeriesCoefficient[#, {x, 0, 0}] &
```

Output is

> -162139892578125000000

Answer (score 5):

```
(-2*x^4 - 5/x)^25 // First @* ExpandAll
```

> ```
> -162139892578125000000
> ```

Comment: Interesting. Simple way of doing it. Thanks!